# How to read multiple lines from Stdin in python,Here's the question and code

Tags: python, algorithm

I usually use Leetcode..just switched to Hackerrank,
So question needs me to read multiple lines of input from stdin and print their answers respectively,
but My answers are printing in a different form.

Here's the Code

```
import sys
arr = sys.stdin.readlines()
ans = ""

for string in arr:
    #a long code
    print(ans)
```

The Expected output needs to be without line gaps in after each line
mine is this..[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess `readlines` is reading _including line ends_. Either use `strip` to remove line ends, or use `input()`

Comment: How do I use input() for anonymous lengths of inputs?

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case, just make sure to `str.strip` or `str.rstrip` each line in the input `arr`.